# Django change and track order status

Tags: python, django

I have a status field in my model with a default value in progress. Whenever a new order is created a default value of in-progress is given to the order. Now I have added a new function, when a customer enters the order id it displays the status of the order. I want to add new functionality to my function in which when the customer enters the order.id and clicks track the order status should automatically change to scheduled and if I update the order status later on it shouldn't show schedule instead the status I will select. What can I add in my views function to make that work?

````
models.py

class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100
   status = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = choices) default="In Progress")
choices = (('Received', 'Received'),
        ('Scheduled', 'Scheduled'), 
        ('Shipped', 'Shipped'),
        ('In Progress','In Progress'),
        )```
````

```
views.py

def order_tracker(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        orderId = request.POST.get('orderId', '')
        try:
            order=Order.objects.filter(pk=orderId)

            if len(order)>0:
                update = Order.objects.filter(pk=orderId)
                updates = []
                for order in update:
                    order.status = 'Scheduled'
                    order.save()
                    updates.append({'status' : order.status})
                    response = json.dumps(updates)
                    return HttpResponse(response)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('{}')
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse('{}')
    return render(request,"status/track.html")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def order_tracker(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        orderId = request.POST.get('orderId', '')
        try:
            order=Order.objects.filter(pk=orderId)

            if len(order)>0:
                update = Order.objects.filter(pk=orderId)
                updates = []
                for order in update:
                    # change order status to scheduled
                    if order.status == 'processing':
                        order.status = 'scheduled'
                        order.save()
                    updates.append({'status' : order.status})
                    response = json.dumps(updates)
                    return HttpResponse(response)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('{}')
        except Exception as e:
            # add some logging here
            return HttpResponse('{}')
    return render(request,"tracker.html")
```

BTW, you seem like getting a list of orders? If you are supposed to only getting one order, please use `Order.objects.get()`, which will raise `DoesNotExist` exception if criteria is not matched.

```py
def order_tracker(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        orderId = request.POST.get('orderId', '')
        try:
            order=Order.objects.get(pk=orderId)
            if order.status == 'processing':
                order.status = 'scheduled'
                order.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status' : order.status})
        except: Order.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({})
    return render(request,"tracker.html")
```

Comment: But if I update the status to shipped, it still shows scheduled.it should only change to scheduled when the customer enters order.id for the first time.

Comment: I'm using ajax i want the list of all all order status chronically

Comment: just put in an if statement, there I updated my answer

Comment: Why are you returning a list of orders if you only accept an order ID, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm trying to get a timeline of order status changes

Comment: Then you need a different model to record the changes. Have a read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension

Comment: @lastly jus wanted to ask you if I create another model , how should I connect that to the order model ? using foreign key?

Comment: Yes using foreign key.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/ Reporter is similar to your Order, Article is similar to your Status

Answer (score 0):

```
def order_tracker(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        orderId = request.POST.get('orderId', '')
        try:
            order=Order.objects.filter(pk=orderId)

            if len(order)>0:
                update = Order.objects.filter(pk=orderId)
                updates = []
                for order in update:
                    order.status = 'Scheduled'
                    order.save()
                    updates.append({'status' : order.status})
                    response = json.dumps(updates)
                    return HttpResponse(response)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('{}')
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse('{}')
    return render(request,"tracker.html")
```

just assign status and save it.